# How to select edge loops intervally in blender?

Tags: selection-tools, select

How can I select edge loops like that, there is a unselected loop between two loops.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case:

Hold `alt` `ctrl` and left click one of the edges, this will select all the edges along the face loop excluding the edges perpendicular to the selected edge, this is called the "edge ring"
[image]

Then from the `Select` menu choose `Checker Deselect` This will deselect every 2nd edge, you can play with it's settings to get something you need.
[image]

Then again from the `Select` menu choose `Select Loops` > `Edge Loops` to select all the loops with a selected edge
[image]

This should give you what you want, it is the fastest way I can think of. There are hot-keys for these commands that once you are use to them make this method of selection very fast

[image]

Happy Blendering